# Maintaining context of type arguments with Mono.Cecil

Tags: c#, mono, mono.cecil

After learning how to properly [access the fields and properties of a List](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16182174/435460) with **Mono.Cecil**, it was pointed out that you need to make sure that the context of the type arguments is maintained on the List object that you're working with (which makes sense).

What's the proper way to do this?

**Edit (based on @Simon's request)**

Given you have a `TypeReference` for a list, for example

```
System.Collections.Generic.List`1<MyNamespace.MyObject>
```

and you want to access it's fields, you'll actually need a `TypeDefinition` for this list. When you attempt to `Resolve` your `TypeReference`, you end up losing the type arguments that were a part of the original `TypeReference` (aka your new `TypeDefinition` will now be for

```
System.Collections.Generic.List`1
```

which will have a `GenericParameter` of `T`).

I have attempted to re-apply the type arguments via code like the following

```
var resolve = myList.Resolve();
resolve.GenericParameters.Clear();
foreach (var p in (myList as GenericInstanceType).GenericArguments)
{
    var gp = new GenericParameter(p.FullName, p.GetElementType().Resolve());
    resolve.GenericParameters.Add(gp);
}
```

This doesn't work, leading to an

```
Member 'MyNamespace.MyObject' is declared in another module and needs to be 
imported
```

error. (If you didn't attempt to repopulate in this fashion, the error would instead be `Member 'T' is declared...`).

Comment: I know what you are getting at but you will need some more context here to make it a viable question for StackOverflow. a code snippet/unit test and the error you get would be best

Comment: You should add a reference to `Mono.Cecil.Rocks` assembly, and use `TypeReferenceRocks.MakeGenericInstanceType` extension method.